# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 with Laravel

Tags: php, json, http, laravel-5.5, guzzle

I am trying to edit a JSON formatted category with PUT method, so I am using guzzleHttp library to parse json requests and responses with laravel 5.5.

My POST, GET methods are working fine when I am trying to grab or insert data into my server, but I am getting error on PUT & DELETE method.

There are two types of errors I am getting :

1. localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
2. Out Of Memory - Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1472200704) (tried to allocate 176128 bytes)

**Console Error :**

[image]

These errors occurs not together just one after another if I request twice in row.

**I have trying to change allocated memory, but it did not work !**

Here are my procedures to handle a request :

**My Controller** :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // get the inputs
    $inputs = [
      "cat_id" => $id,
      "cat_name" => $request->input('cat_name'),
      "cat_slug" => $request->input('cat_slug'),
      "cat_description" => $request->input('cat_description'),
      "cat_parent_id" => $request->input('cat_parent_id')
    ];

    // post to the database
    $response = $this->categories->update($id, $inputs);

    if($response['success']){
      $message = $response['message'];

      Session::flash('success', 'Category is successfully saved !'.' Server Response Message : '.$message);

      return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }else{
      $message = $response['message'];

      Session::flash('success', 'Category is not successfully saved !'.' Server Response Message : '.$message);

      return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // If the edit page should be shown
    //return redirect()->route('categories.edit', $id);
}
```

**My Repository** :

```
public function update($id, $category){
  return $this->update("categories/{$id}", $category);
}
```

**And My Custom GuzzleHttpRequest.php** :

```
protected function update($url, $data){

  $formatted_data = json_encode($data);

  $request = $this->client->request('PUT', $url, [
    'body' => $formatted_data
  ]);

  $response = json_decode( $request->getBody()->getContents() , true );

  return $response;
}
```

**My Server Accepts JSON formatted inputs : https://rest-banai.herokuapp.com/**

**Edited :**

**And My Edit Form** :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['categories.update', $category['cat_id']], 'method' => 'PUT', 'data-parsley-validate' => '']) !!}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('cat_name', 'Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('cat_name', $category['cat_name'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter category name ...', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '50']) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('cat_slug', 'Slug:') }}
        {{ Form::text('cat_slug', $category['cat_slug'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a slug word ...', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '50', 'data-parsley-type' => 'alphanum']) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('cat_description', 'Description:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('cat_description', $category['cat_description'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3', 'placeholder' => 'Enter description of the category ...', 'maxlength' => '255']) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('cat_parent_id', 'Parent Category:') }}
        <br />
        {{ Form::select('cat_parent_id', $cat_array, null, ['placeholder' => $cat_parent_name]) }}
        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        {{ Form::submit('SAVE', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm']) }}
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am not sure what is I am doing wrong here, any expert, please help me with the issue as I am new with Guzzle and JSON working with Laravel, it will be appreciated.
And If anythings unclear here, please suggest to edit.

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: the update url is on your server?

Comment: update url is : https://rest-banai.herokuapp.com/categories/id , I have set guzzle client base_uri to http://rest-banai.herokuapp.com/ and then passing categories/id to update

Comment: @madalinivascu can you show me the syntax for that on my $request part? is that header var or body var?

Answer (score 0):

Change your request to

```
$request = $this->client->request('PUT', $url,['json'=> $data]);
```

Comment: It is not working, please check my edits, there may have some problem with the form.

Comment: what do you mean by not working, what result do you get?

Comment: I am still getting the error : localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: so you have 2 site 1.rest-banai.herokuapp.com/categories/id and the second is the site with the view and the controller from the question,yes?

Comment: rest-banai.herokuapp.com/categories/id < this is just the node.js server which I made for working with databases as a resful service. and I am developing a website in my localhost with the view and controller

Comment: what did you add for delete method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156659/discussion-between-ray-dvard-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

You are using resourceful routes, and yet you have a lot of complexity in your code. This quite frankly in my opinion is completely unnecessary. I will accomplish what you are doing in the following way:

## Routes

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
```

## Controller

```
public function edit(Category $category)
{
    return view('category.edit', compact('category'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    try {
        $category->update($request->all()->except(['_token']));

        Session::flash('success', 'Category is successfully saved !');
    } catch(\Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('error', 'Unable to update category!');    
    }

    return redirect(route('category.index'));
}
```

## HTML

### category/edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => route('categories.update', $category), 'method' => 'PUT', 'data-parsley-validate' => '']) !!}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('cat_name', 'Name:') }}
    {{ Form::text('cat_name', $category->cat_name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter category name ...', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '50']) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('cat_slug', 'Slug:') }}
    {{ Form::text('cat_slug', $category->cat_slug, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a slug word ...', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '50', 'data-parsley-type' => 'alphanum']) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('cat_description', 'Description:') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('cat_description', $category->cat_description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3', 'placeholder' => 'Enter description of the category ...', 'maxlength' => '255']) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('cat_parent_id', 'Parent Category:') }}
    <br />
    {{ Form::select('cat_parent_id', $cat_array, null, ['placeholder' => $cat_parent_name]) }}
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    {{ Form::submit('SAVE', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm']) }}
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

```

Comment: Okay, can you explain exactly in which lines did you reduce complexity of processing request? I can see only you have wrap my input arrays in one line and that's it. Still you are requesting for result to repository, and repository is requesting for result to GuzzleHtttpRequest.php ... and for your information I get the same error.

Comment: Refer to the laravel.log file to see what errors are occuring.

Comment: I use this approach for CRUD operations when using resourceful routing. Fat more easy to implement.